# Unable to let user upload profile picture in sign up process (Parse.com/JS SDK)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

Using parse.com and the JavaScript SDK. The code should let a user sign up and upload a profile picture.

Updated, this is the code I'm using that is returning an error when trying to sign up a user the console message `is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

```
> $('#SignUp').click(function(e) {
>     UserSignUp(); });
> 
> 
> function UserSignUp() {
> 
>     var user = new Parse.User();
>     userFirstname = $('#firstnamesu').val();
>     userLastname = $('#lastnamesu').val();
>     userUsername = $('#usernamesu').val();
>     userGender = $('#gendersu').val();
>     Email = $('#emailsu').val();
>     PWP = $('#passwordsu').val();
> 
>     user.set("FirstName", userFirstname);
>     user.set("LastName", userLastname);
>     user.set("username", userUsername);
>     user.set("gender", userGender);
>     user.set("email", Email);
>     user.set("password", PWP);
> 
> 
>      var fileUploadControl = $("#pic")[0];    if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {    var file =
> fileUploadControl.files[0];    var name = "photo.png";
> 
>    var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
> 
>    //put this inside if {    parseFile.save().then(function() {    //
> The file has been saved to Parse.    }, function(error) {    // The
> file either could not be read, or could not be saved to Parse.
>     });
> 
>     // Be sure of ur parameters name
>     // prod is extend of my class in parse from this: var prod = new products();
>     user.set("ProfilePic", parseFile);
>     user.save();    } ////////////Runs parse after the SignUp button has been clicked by the user////////////////////
> 
> $('#SignUp').click(function(e) {
>     UserSignUp(); });
> 
>     user.signUp(null, {
>         success: function(user) {
>             if (!user.existed()) {
>                 window.location.href = "user_home.html";
>             } else {
>                 alert("NO WAY BUDDY");
>             }
>         },
>         error: function(user, error) {
> 
>         }
>     });
```

Comment: It's unclear where the "Uncaught TypeError" is occurring. Is it happening when you are checking the length of the files or when saving? Can you provide a jsfiddle with a more complete example of your issue?

Comment: It looks like you're following the example on the [JS Guide](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#files) pretty closely. I see `.length` in only one place in your code, and so it seems as though jQuery cannot find your `input`. If you type `$("#pic")[0]` in your console, does it return your input?

Comment: @adamdport it returns <input type="file" id="pic" aria-invalid="false"> I've updated my code example above to show what I'm now using. Thanks for looking at this!

Comment: Have you tried putting the `prod.set` inside the success function of `parseFile.save()`?

Comment: I meant `user.set`, oops.

Comment: @adamdport cheers, I managed to sort this, I added my answer below. Thks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to answer my own question by using the following code. Basically it was a case of refactoring the code into a more logical order that resolved it. The issue wasn't helped by another issue I had here which just confused matters further.[Issue with parse.com user signup not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251556/issue-with-parse-com-user-signup-not-working)

```
   $('#SignUp').click(function(e) {

    UserSignUp();
});


function UserSignUp() {

      var fileUploadControl = $("#pic")[0];
    if (fileUploadControl.files.length > 0) {
       var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
       var name = "photo.png";


   var user = new Parse.User();

   var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);
   userFirstname = $('#firstnamesu').val();
   userLastname = $('#lastnamesu').val();
   userUsername = $('#usernamesu').val();
   userGender = $('#gendersu').val();
   Email = $('#emailsu').val();
   PWP = $('#passwordsu').val();


   user.set("ProfilePic", parseFile);
   user.set("FirstName", userFirstname);
   user.set("LastName", userLastname);
   user.set("username", userUsername);
   user.set("gender", userGender);
   user.set("email", Email);
   user.set("password", PWP);


var uri = encodeURI('http://XXXX.com/XXXX.html');

  user.signUp(null, {
    success: function(user) {

         if (!user.existed()) {
                window.location.href = uri;
            } 

    },
    error: function(user, error) {
      // Show the error message somewhere and let the user try again.

    }
  });


};
}
```

Comment: Can you specify exactly what changed and why the problem happened to help others in a similar situation?

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion, and it's going to make your code a bit more lengthy but it will show you where the error is occurring.

```
function ifUndeforNull(val){
 var ret = false;
 try{
   if((val == undefined)|| (val==null)){
    ret = true;
   } 
  }catch(ex){
   console.log("Error:"+ex);
  }
 return ret;
}
```

so then you check if your vals are undefined or null.

```
if(ifUndeforNull(userFirstname)){ 
   console.log('User First Name Null or Undefined');
}
```

wrapping the entirety in a try{} catch{} with logging would also help.

Lastly, I'd declare the variables such as userFirstName with var, as sometimes browsers can be annoyingly non-standard when that is not specified.